# Obtaining a regression table with texreg in Lyx

Tags: lyx, texreg

I'm using the packages knitr and texreg in a Lyx document and I've got this problem. When I'm using a float table in Lyx, I've always got this lines before the table in the pdf:

```
## Version: 1.36.23
## Date: 2017-03-03
## Author: Philip Leifeld (University of Glasgow)
##
## Please cite the JSS article in your publications – see citation("texreg").
```

How could I get only the table without these lines?

Comment: A minimal example will probably help people help you.

Comment: This information is only displayed when the package is loaded for the first time. Are you loading the package in the body of the document or in the `knitr` header at the beginning of the document?